# device rotation: portrait- landscape

Tags: iphone

I am working on iphone application in which i am showing camera view for zoom in zoom out using scroller.
I want to add functionality, when a user rotate device from portarit to landscape or vice versa then camera view should adjust accordingly.

how can i fix it
Please help

thanks,
Aaryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your UIViewController needs to implement the following methods:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```